# How to reduce count of binding exceptions when binding height and width in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, double

I want to bind items width and height to a model.

For some items width and height is specified but most of them should be set to "Auto" mode.

So i created model with property:

```
    public double? Height
    {
        get
        {
            return this.height;
        }

        set
        {
            this.height = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Height");
        }
    }
```

And i bind it to my view.

In case if **height == null** my control size is set to auto and this is OK.
But i have exceptions:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=Height;
target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')
```

How can i force my control to set height to 'Auto' and avoid exceptions generation?

Comment: Found that we can just remove nullable '?' sign and set by default double to NAN. Double.NaN; and this will solve all problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what the `TargetNullValue` property is used for within binding expersions:

```
Height="{Binding Height, TargetNullValue=auto}"
```

This should work for what you need.  You could also edit your get method to handle the null event, but you may have to change the data type to object to be able to return `auto`:

```
public object Height
{
    get
    {
        if (this.height == null) return "auto";
        return this.height;
    }
    set
    {
        this.height = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write that Double.NaN is 'auto' :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to your Height property and use a ValueConverter.
Implement the interface IValueConverter and add it to your binding. This way you can return 'auto' when there is an invalid value.

this should be in your xaml

```
<res:HeightConverter x:key=HeightConverter/>

<label height="{Binding MyHeight, ValueConverter={StaticResource HeightConverter}"/>
```

And this in your converter

```
Public Class HeightConverter : IValueConverter ......

if(value = Nothing){Return "auto"}
```

Just some code out of my head so don't mind any syntax issues, but thats basically it

You can use this to modify and override some excess values as well. Gives a lot of flexibility